# Replace the names of a list in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, replace

I am trying to replace the names of a list in a dataframe (column C):

**Name's list (small example, the list is too large):**

```
Jack
Liam
John
Ethan
George
...
```

**Small dataframe exemple:**

```
       A          B                                   C
  French      house                Phone <phone_numbers>
 English      house                 email <adresse_mail>
  French  apartment                      my name is Liam
  French      house                         Hello George
 English  apartment   Ethan, my phone is <phone_numbers>
```

**My script:**

```
import re
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series

df = pd.read_excel('data_frame.xlsx')
data = Series.to_string(df['C'])

first_names = open('names_list.txt', 'r')
names_read = first_names.readlines()

def names(data):

    names_regex = re.compile(r'\b%s\b' % r'\b|\b'.join(map(re.escape, names_read)))
    replace_names = names_regex.sub('<name>', data)

    return replace_names

no_names = names(data)
print(no_names)
```

As a output, I have my entire dataframe without any modification...

**I expected:**

```
                                  C
              Phone <phone_numbers>
               email <adresse_mail>
                  my name is <name>
                       Hello <name>
<name>, my phone is <phone_numbers>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
name_list = ['Jack', 'Liam', 'John', 'Ethan']
mydf = pd.DataFrame({'C': ['Phone <phone_numbers>', 'email <adresse_mail>', 'my name is Liam', 'Hello George', 'Ethan, my phone is <phone_numbers>']})
```

You could define a regex based on your name list. You then match these values with the column `C` and replace them with a `apply lambda`

```
match = mydf.C.str.extractall('(' + '|'.join(name_list) + ')').reset_index().set_index('level_0').rename(columns={0: 'name'})
mydf = pd.concat([mydf, match], axis=1)
condition = mydf.match.notnull()
mydf.loc[condition, 'C'] = mydf[condition].apply(lambda x: x['C'].replace(x['name'], '<name>'), axis=1)
```

Output

```
                                     C  match    name
0                Phone <phone_numbers>    NaN     NaN
1                 email <adresse_mail>    NaN     NaN
2                    my name is <name>    0.0    Liam
3                         Hello <name>    0.0  George
4  <name>, my phone is <phone_numbers>    0.0   Ethan
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply replace them with looping through the values of given column:

```
import pandas as pd

l = [
['French','house','Phone <phone_numbers>'],
['English','house','email <adresse_mail>'],
['French','apartment','my name is Liam'],
['French','house','Hello George'],
['English','apartment','Ethan, my phone is <phone_numbers>']
]

names = [
'Jack',
'Liam',
'John',
'Ethan',
'George'
]

df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns = list('ABC'))

for i in names:
  df.C = df.C.str.replace(i,'<name>')

print(df)
```